# locate xcdatamodeld file in swift package

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to build an application for `iOS` and `watchOS`. Both projects would use the same domain model and for that purpose I would like to split my codebase into distinct platform projects and at least one local swift package that contains the `xcdatamodeld` file.

But using Xcode it's not possible to move the file from the iOS project into the swift package I created.

Any suggestions what going on here or how I could solve this problem?

Many thanks in advice!

Comment: There are several articles on this if you do some research, [here](https://ishabazz.dev/blog/2020/7/5/using-core-data-with-swift-package-manager) is one

Comment: Yes, I‘m familiar with this article. But as I said, I can‘t drag the xcdatamodeld file into my sources folder and I don‘t know why ‍♂️

Comment: Try to create the model directly in the package and then restart Xcode

Comment: Alright, I‘ll give it a try!

Comment: It works, kind of...after creating the model file. It's possible to generate the data classes. But what's strange is, that I can't select the package as location to generate the classes to. What do I miss?

Comment: You don't have a target in the same way as an Xcode for a swift package instead any source file that is inside the Source/<Target folder> folder of the package is part of that package target. So all you need to make sure is to _not_ include it in any of the Xcode targets and save them in the correct folder.